# Error including precompiled header

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am writing a code for console application in using Visual studio 2010 on windows 7. I have included the libraries used in this but when I am building the program with header files only it is unable to include "stdafx.h" header file. This is my code.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stgetriggersample.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
error C1189: #error :  "include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH"
```

"stdafx.h" header file is present in my current directory.

**Update**
The content of "**stgetriggersample.h**" is

```
// StGETriggerSample.h : main header file for the PROJECT_NAME application
//
//#include"stdafx.h"
#pragma once

#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
#include"stdafx.h"
    #error "include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif

#include "resource.h"       // main symbols


// CStGETriggerSampleApp:
// See StGETriggerSample.cpp for the implementation of this class
//

class CStGETriggerSampleApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    CStGETriggerSampleApp();

// Overrides
    public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance();

// Implementation

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

extern CStGETriggerSampleApp theApp;
```

The content of "**stdafx.h**" is:

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>



// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

I tried writing the code with the option **Not Using Precompiled Headers** but still I get the same error.

How this can be corrected. Thanks

Comment: rebuild? or clean and then build?

Comment: @thinkerou There is no effect of doing so.

Comment: And what about `stdafx.cpp`? Is it in your project? Presence of h-file in the directory is not only requirements, `stdafx.cpp` have to be compiled within your project (you must see `stdafx.cpp` and `stdafx.h` in the project explorer)

Comment: **stdafx.cpp** is also there. @VolAnd

Comment: It expects you to #include the MFC headers in your stdafx.h file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have been trying to fix this so hard, that, in fact, you have broken something. Let's go through proper configuration of pre-compiled headers usage in Visual Studio (I will use options names from VS2012):

1. Enable usage of PCH: Project Properties -> `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Precompiled Headers` -> `Precompiled Header` -> `Use (/Yu)`.
2. Set name of precompiled header: Project Properties -> `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Precompiled Headers` -> `Precompiled Header File`. In your case you should see there standard PCH name (`stdafx.h`). You may change that if you want.
3. (In fact, the most important step) Enable PCH generation: Header is not enough. You also need a `.cpp` file, that is responsible for PCH content generation (since only source files can be compiled). In you case, you have default `stdafx.cpp` attached to your project. Click it with RMB, then: `Configuration Properties` -> `C/C++` -> `Precompiled Headers` -> `Precompiled Header` -> `Create (/Yc)`.

From now on, first non-empty line of every source file attached to your project (including the one from step 3, responsible for PCH generation)  should look like this:

```
#include "PCH_NAME"
```

Where `PCH_NAME` is the name of precompiled header set in step 2.

After all these settings are set this way, I would suggest you to:

1. Clean your solution.
2. Check in project properties paths of `Output Directory` and `Intermediate Directory`. Delete them (I hope they don't contain any code - they shouldn't).
3. In solution folder (*), you should also see folder with name like: `your solution name-cc50b4e6`. Delete it.

This will make full reset of your solution (including IntelliSense database etc.). Then, open your project and compile it.

**(*)** - In your solution folder, **by default**. If you have valid `Fallback Location` set, it will be placed there.

Comment: in the first step you are suggesting to **Use (/Yu)** and in 3rd step you are suggesting **Create (/Yc)**. What is difference between these two.
After doing the correction as described by you my problem is not solved. Please help me

Comment: You didn't read carefully. `Use (/Yu)` must be set for project. `Create (/Yc)` must be set for `.cpp` file responsible for PCH generation. "In you case, you have default stdafx.cpp attached to your project. Click **it** with RMB, [...]". **it** refers to `.cpp` file, not project.

Answer (score 0):

In the code:

```
#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
    #include"stdafx.h"
    #error "include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif
```

it looks like StGETriggerSample.h is checking that stdafx.h has been #included by looking for the compile guard macro AFXWIN_H__.  However, stdafx.h is not actually defining this guard macro, it's just relying on the statment "#pragma once" to avoid multiple inclusions.  So even if stdafx.h has been included, the #error statement will always trigger.

To fix, add the compile guard

```
#ifndef __STDAFX_H__
#define __STDAFX_H__

// ... yadda yadda yadda...

#endif // __STDAFX_H__
```

to your stdafx.h.  You can remove the #pragma once statement from stdafx.h if you want to, but it's not necessary.

As an aside, your code is also attempting to #include stdafx.h if it hasn't already been included, but then causing the compile error anyways.  I'm pretty sure you only want to do one or the other...

Comment: Mark Morrison I have added the compile guard as suggested by you but still there is no difference. Do i need to remove or add anything else.